# Can I run a javascript file using geth attach?

Tags: go-ethereum, javascript, quorum, geth-debugging

I want to automatize one thing. Aftert installing the Quorum nodes, I have to run:

```
docker exec -it quorum_node1_1 geth attach /qdata/dd/geth.ipc
```

Then I am pasting the JS code

But I want to automatize this in a bash script. Can I somehow pass the javascript file as an argument in this command?

EDIT:

I have created a command like this:

```
docker exec -it quorum_node1_1 geth --exec "loadScript(\"/deploy.js\")" attach /qdata/dd/geth.ipc
```

But when I run it it returns

```
false
```

And that's all...